# How can i add object into static array

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-contacts, android-cursor

the code idea is originally like this , i want to add the persons from android contacts

```
public final class People{
        public static Person[] PEOPLE = {
        new Person(1, R.drawable.person1, "Betty Boo", "is having her hair cut at 6pm"),
        new Person(1, R.drawable.person2, "Lisa James", "is going to Avicii live ft.. event"),
        };
}
```

in activity

```
    ViewGroup people = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.people);
    for(int i = 0; i < People.PEOPLE.length; i++){
            people.addView(People.inflatePersonView(this, people, People.PEOPLE[i]));
    }
```

i want to put the items into array from the query , my attempts were as follows

```
public final class People{


    public static Person[] PEOPLE(ContentResolver cr) {

        Person[] PEOPLE = {};

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "starred=?",
                        new String[] {"1"}, null);

        int i=0;
        int contactID;
        String contactName;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            contactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            PEOPLE[i] = new Person(contactID, R.drawable.person1, contactName, contactName);

            i++;
        }
        cursor.close();

        return PEOPLE;
    }
}
```

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array isn't the most appropriate data structure for this, as it cannot be resized to add new elements (well, it can, but you actually need to create a new array and copy the contents -- definitely not suitable for adding items one by one).

I would suggest using a `List<Person>` instead (using `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` as the actual class). More or less like this:

```
public static List<Person> PEOPLE(ContentResolver cr) {

    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    ...
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       ...
       people.add(new Person(...);
    }     

    return people;
}
```

To iterate over a List, you can use a for loop:

```
for (Person person : People.PEOPLE(cr)) {
    ... person
```

or, if you prefer, a more traditional

```
List<Person> people = People.PEOPLE(cr);
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    Person person = people.get(i);
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by for ? the for loop ?

Comment: should pass resolver "for (int i = 0; i < People.PEOPLE(cr).size(); i++)"

Comment: Yes, it's a method. In that case, forget about the `for (int i = 0` loop. It will call the method EVERY TIME, and you don't want that.

Comment: @matiash you are awesome ! , testing now
so the loop should run like this ? "for (Person person : People.PEOPLE(cr))"

Comment: it works like charm !!
[my project check it](https://plus.google.com/b/107409945821339773111/+ProBamNet/posts/GaDmD8fW4f2)

Comment: @HanyAlsamman I'm glad. Don't forget to accept the answer if you thought it was useful ;)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :( :( , yes it's very useful

Comment: last think if i want to use your way without "i++" how i can get the index ?
"People.PEOPLE(cr).get(i))"

Comment: @HanyAlsamman When iterating (with `for(item : collection)`) you don't have the index, but you have the item. I have posted another example in case you need the index.